# memory instruments not working in xcode

Tags: xcode, instruments, memory-leaks, allocation

After some upgrades to Xcode i am experiencing a strange situation:
when i start instruments to profile my apps (both on ios or mac) it works well with all the instruments (for example cpu monitor, or i/o monitors) but i cannot use the memory management ones: Allocations, Leaks, Object graph. If i start the profile window by clicking on leaks it just opens an empty "Instruments document", and if i drag them from the library panel they don't show up, but all the others do. Anybody is experiencing this behaviour? Maybe some missing library?

My Xcode version is "Version 4.2 Build 4D199" and my instruments version is "Version 4.2 (4233)"

Comment: I've got the exact same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: the update to 4.2.1 solved it. I did a complete uninstall and reinstall to be sure. Weird..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by updating Xcode to version 4.2.1 (Build 4D502).

One thing that I noticed, since I've installed Xcode using the Mac App Store, was that the update process behaves like the install - it downloads an app called "Install Xcode" which you run to install/update. So be sure to run the installation app after first time download or update.